# Streaming video that's being recorded?

Tags: video, streaming, live

Is streaming video while it's being recorded possible? If so how? What Programs would someone need?

Comment: I'd suggest you add some more detail - such as the comment you made on Mulvya's answer.

Comment: Exactly as the Dr says above. You'll get much better answers, keep your question open and won't waste people's time answering something you already know if you provide as much details about your environment/problem as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) is a free multi-platform solution that I know of.

Comment: I actually meant streaming from a phone to PC! And OBS is cool, i already knew about it.